# does overheating laptop means something was already damaged in the hardware?

Tags: laptop, cpu, shutdown, cooling, overheating

Excuse my ignorance, but I am just not familiar with these stuff.
My first laptop was an `HP` (it was the model before Pavilion Series) with processor `Intel Athlon II`, and it was a great experience, it took him 5~6 years before I can disposed of it. Symptom is: `just 15 minutes after booting, it overheats and immediately shutdown`, I know its overheating, because I would actually get burn if I keep my skin near its exhaust for more than 1 minute

I did not bother asking for fix/repair, because its 6 years old anyway, I need upgrade. So ~last year, I bought my 2nd laptop which I currently use now, its `ASUS X550Z`, its processor is `AMD A10` (its quadcore) and I bought for ~$640, at first its good, never had seen my CPU utilization go over 70%. Now even before its warranty ends, its already showing almost the same symptoms of my first laptop. It overheats at its exhaust, you cannot finish a single movie because it would shutdown at the middle, you cannot run applications like I used to play with it at the first 6 months I bought it. It would just simply shutdown. And its warranty is not yet even expired.

I probably can go for their customer support and let them check my laptop under warranty. they might just clean it up, re-apply thermal paste, but I wonder if they would replace hardwares that might be damaged due to overheating , so I do not know if it would refresh to at least near the state the way I bought it.

(1) Does overheating can damage hardware?

(2) Is damaged hardware due to overheating would be more noticeable than just sudden shutdown?

(3) If auto-shutdown is only due to Dust + Thermal Paste, does that mean my good old `HP` laptop only needs cleaning from professional cleaning and re-applying thermal paste?

(4) Does "cleaning dust" and "re-applying thermal paste" would help me get my laptop near its "brand-new" state? Or should I just give it up too?

Comment: For how long you were facing this over heating issue. Most of the times cleaning the fan and applying the thermal paste would solve the problem.

Comment: @vembutech for 2 months already, (~8 months after buying it).

Comment: The CPU fan is running?

Comment: @vembutech yes, it is running, it would actually blow soo hard especially at the start of boot up. If I place my hand near the exhaust, i can feel a very small push of air. Actually, I tried doing google on how to keep making the CPU fan rotate like crazy. but apparently, no software supports this laptop.

Comment: Are you using the laptop in dusty environments or perhaps in bed or on the couch? If so, the heat spreaders near the fan may be clogged with dust which makes them much less efficient. I would suggest you open it up (or ask the store where you bought it to do so) and clean it out. (don't use water, for obvious reasons)

Comment: @cascer1 you can be right, this laptop stayed in my room since it was bought. I have a cooling pad with 70 cm FAN where I put my laptop to rest when it is not on my lap, so that cooling pad might be blowing dust too on the ventilation of the laptop at its bottom. hmmm.

Comment: You said that you have warranty so, Call them and lock a complaint and check what's causing the problem.

Comment: @vembutech okay thank you, i think that's what I would do first. its 2 weeks anyway before its warranty ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your main question: **No**, the fact that the laptop overheats does *not* mean that something was damaged already. A little cleaning probably wouldn't hurt, though.

1. Overheating can damage hardware, this shouldn't happen in normal use-cases though, because the computer should shut down to protect itself before this happens.
2. The symptoms of damaged hardware depend on what was damaged. In your case, I assume the shutdowns are caused by overheating, and the computer protecting itself. Most components can handle temperatures over the shutdown limit, the temperature limit should be set so that no hardware is damaged before or during the shutdown.
3. If it is the case that the old HP was indeed just dirty, cleaning it out and maybe re-applying thermal paste will help. I wouldn't expect it to run modern workloads with ease, though. Running modern programs on a 6-year old system can be quite a strain so I expect it will get very hot due to the high load.
4. Removing dust from the laptop will help it cool more efficiently, allowing it to maintain a high load for longer and run cooler on a lower load. There are a lot of factors that can slow down a computer though, such as a fragmented hard disk or running many programs at once.

Comment: thank you for giving detailed advise. I am so happy to hear that my old `HP` laptop can be used again. I won't give up on this laptop yet, looking forward to its cleaning and thermal paste re application.